# TextField Not horizontal scrolling with text[Titanium]

Tags: textarea, titanium, horizontal-scrolling

I want the textarea to scroll horizontally once the test string has exceeded the width of the textarea. I tried the below code, but however, it does not work for some reason.

I also tried adding a wrapper view to scroll view and adding the textarea to the wrapper view; but that does not work either.

How can I fix this ?

```
 var scroll = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
     top:40,
     left:230,
     width:290,
     height:50
});
win.add(scroll);

var textType = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
   backgroundColor:'#E6E6E6',
   borderColor:'blue',
   borderRadius:10,
   top:0,
   left:0,
   width:290,
   height:50,
   font:{fontSize:26, fontFamily:customFont},
   editable:false,
   enabled:false,
   textAlign:'right',
   scrollable:true
  });
 scroll.add(textType);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this sound really simple but, for default the text area is vertical scrollable. and this is the only behavior i know of it. i have tried different properties like:

```
    layout:"horizontal",
    horizontalWrap:true,
    scrollable:true,
```

But this has not resolve the issue.